# what 'select#category' refter to?

Tags: jquery

what `select#category` refer to, which one is the element id?
can u also explain this `select option:selected`?

```
$("select#category").change(function () 
{
  if ($("select option:selected").val() == 0) {
   $('div[id^="product_"]').hide();
   $('#waiting').show();
}
   $('#waiting').hide();
   $('div[id^="product_"]').hide();
   if ($('div[id="product_'+$("select option:selected").val()+'"]:visible')) 
   {
     $('div[id="product_'+$("select option:selected").val()+'"]').show();
   }
}
});
```

so if "id" involved why it also puts select keyword there?('cause i think without the select part, it's still unique and can refer to that specific element)

Answer (score 3):

`select#category`
it refers to a `select` element with id `category`

`select option:selected`
refers to selected `option`s under `select` elements in the page (Note: it can return multiple elements)

In this case you may want to replace `$("select option:selected").val()` with `$(this).val()` - it will give the value of the selected option

Comment: so if "id" involved why it put also select keyword there?('cause i think without the select part, it's still unique)

Comment: @SafeTobe the `select` is not at all needed